# In Tableview, I want to know how to i set multiline UILabel in cell last position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

In `UITableView`, I want to know how to i set multiline`UILabel` (Needs to update dynamically.) in cell last position, I want to calculate for `UILabel` count and set multiline in tableview

Comment: This Uilable is for Long Description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ashu you can set tableView cell height dynamically for that particular cell.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 41.0
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 100
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Something like code mentioned above.

Comment: @AshuDesigner but make sure that the number of lines should be 0 and put constraints on all four edges. (top, bottom, leading, trailing) and height should not be fixed.

Comment: ok alomost done, but some little cut from bottom side uilable

Comment: @AshuDesigner check ur cell height and the label is properly placed in table view cell.

Comment: Yes , Now i am checking Height of cell